# How to bind parent scope property?

Tags: angularjs

I need get 'c' attribute inside child element from parent (see in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykmfs))
Is it possible?

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <box c="yellow">
       <item>item</item>
    </box>
</div>    

angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('box', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
})
.directive('item', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {c:'='},
        template: '<div>c:{{c}}</div>'
    };
});
```

Comment: try to override the link function and access scope.$parent

Answer (score 2):

Since your item directive defines an isolate scope, you need to define an attribute on item for each scope property you want.  So at a minimum you'll need:

```
<item c="c">item</item>
```

Now, the `c` to the right of the `=` needs to be a scope property on the box directive, so create a linking function to make that happen:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.c = attrs.c;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/nbpWz/).

Answer (score 0):

When you use translcude, the parent dom object is not actually a parent in scopes-tree. Nice scope inheritance description here:

[What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

You can get it directly, but it is not a beautiful way:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('box', function(){
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: { c: '@' },
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});

app.directive('item', function(){
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<div>c:{{$parent.$$prevSibling.c}}</div>'
  };
});
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/YuYry9?p=preview

I believe there are more ng-like ways of doing that...